# Accessing private instance variables of parent from child class?

Tags: java, oop, class, inheritance, polymorphism

Let's say we have a class `foo` which has a private instance variable `bar`.

Now let us have another class, `baz`, which `extends foo`. Can non-static methods in `baz` access `foo`'s variable `bar` if there is no accessor method defined in `foo`?

I'm working in Java, by the way.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No, not according to the [java language specification, 3rd edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6.8):

> **6.6.8 Example: private Fields, Methods, and Constructors**
>
> A private
>   class member or constructor is
>   accessible only within the body of the
>   top level class (§7.6) that encloses
>   the declaration of the member or
>   constructor. It is not inherited by
>   subclasses.

But regardless of this language restriction, you *can* [access private fields through reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html):

```
Field privateStringField = 
   MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("privateString");
privateStringField.setAccessible(true);

String fieldValue = (String) privateStringField.get(privateObject);
System.out.println("fieldValue = " + fieldValue);
```

Comment: use can protected on instance variables

Comment: Super just added a function to a library using your workaround.

Comment: Thanks @Wim.  Here's an example with full classes based on this if someone wants to just copy paste to test: https://coding-stream-of-consciousness.com/2019/06/11/java-get-parent-class-private-variable-in-sub-class/.

Comment: *Caveat:* You can access `private` members of the super class if both super class and subclass are within scope of the same top-level class.

Answer (score 24):

No, for that you should use `protected.`

Comment: Actually, you should use a protected setter in case the private variable is removed from a future version of the class.

Answer (score 6):

For questions like this, where is a table found on the website here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Basically you want public or protected variable to be declared in foo since these are the variables that subclasses inherit from their parent and therefore seen in baz.

Answer (score 2):

To use a private variable of a super class in a sub class, an accessor method is required. 
Else use the protected modifier instead of private.

Answer (score 1):

Child classes can not access private members (which is the whole point of private access control).

Answer (score 1):

*...if there is no accessor method defined in foo?*

You need accessors. Besides, take care of inheritance, Should that var really be in parent? Remember IS-A check..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access private variables in descendent classes.  Normally you'd want to use "protected" or "package" (the default) level access for this.  However if you want to be really tricky, you can resort to using reflection and [AccessibleObject](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html) to get at it.
I wouldn't recommend doing that for production code unless you are really in a bind; for testing, etc., it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

The private variable(s) of a class invariably has a scope inside that class. If it has to be shared among the subclasses, it should be declared "protected"

Answer (score 0):

Private members exist(inherited) in instances of child classes .Since, object of Sub class is also an object of Super class, but it is not visible for the sub class

They are accessible indirectly through non-private methods of Super class. These methods can access and manipulate private members

Answer (score 0):

No,bar variable will not be accessible to baz. bar varible should be either protected or public .

Answer (score 0):

Without an accessor method, it's not possible. You have to use a getter setter to access private data members from the superclass.